# launch file error: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I study book "Programming Robots with ROS - Morgan Quigley, Brian Gerkey& William D. Smart" in chapter 14. stockroom-bot
when run launch file marker.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="marker_size" default="12.3"/> 
  <arg name="max_new_marker_error" default="0.2"/>
  <arg name="max_track_error" default="0.8"/>
  <arg name="cam_image_topic" default="/head_camera/rgb/image_raw"/>
  <arg name="cam_info_topic" default="/head_camera/rgb/camera_info"/>
  <arg name="output_frame" default="/base_link"/>
  <node name="ar_track_alvar" pkg="ar_track_alvar" type="individualMarkersNoKinect" respawn="false" output="screen" args="$(arg marker_size) $(arg max_new_marker_error) $(arg max_track_error) $(arg cam_image_topic) $(arg cam_info_topic) $(arg output_frame)" /> 
  <arg name="tag_rot" default="0 0 0 0 0 -1.57">
  <arg name="tag_trans" default="0 -0.28 -0.1 0 0 0">

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_0_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_0 ar_0_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_1_up" args="$(arg tag_rot)  ar_marker_1 ar_1_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_2_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_2 ar_2_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_3_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_3 ar_3_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_4_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_4 ar_4_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_5_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_5 ar_5_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_6_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_6 ar_6_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_7_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_7 ar_7_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_8_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_8 ar_8_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_9_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_9 ar_9_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_10_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_10 ar_10_up 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="ar_11_up" args="$(arg tag_rot) ar_marker_11 ar_11_up 100"/>
 

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_0" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_0_up item_0 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_1" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_1_up item_1 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_2" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_2_up item_2 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_3" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_3_up item_3 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_4" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_4_up item_4 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_5" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_5_up item_5 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_6" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_6_up item_6 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_7" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_7_up item_7 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_8" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_8_up item_8 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_9" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_9_up item_9 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_10" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_10_up item_10 100"/>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="item_11" args="$(arg tag_trans) ar_11_up item_11 100"/>
</launch>
```

--then appear error message

```
... logging to /home/ho/.ros/log/da9b7b56-1299-11e7-83ee-000c29c6431a/roslaunch-ubuntu-51819.log

Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: mismatched tag: line 38, column 2
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

how can fix it?
I run in indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257939/launch-file-error:-invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax/) by [deokisys](https://answers.ros.org/users/29833/deokisys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2017-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are missing `/` in the following two tags.

```
<arg name="tag_rot" default="0 0 0 0 0 -1.57" /> 
<arg name="tag_trans" default="0 -0.28 -0.1 0 0 0" />
```

---

Originally posted by [tngan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29837/tngan/) with karma: 46 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Replace these lines:

```
<arg name="tag_rot" default="0 0 0 0 0 -1.57"/> 
<arg name="tag_trans" default="0 -0.28 -0.1 0 0 0"/>
```

You are missing a couple of `/`

---

Originally posted by [angeltop](https://answers.ros.org/users/29793/angeltop/) with karma: 351 on 2017-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1